# SVG USE XLINK sibling?

Tags: svg

I have a reusable SVG component that contains some templated content. As part of the component default function, I'd like to include a shadow/reflection visual effect.

So, easy, right; `use` and done. Except, here's a reduced example to show the problem I'm having:

```
<svg>
    <use xlink:href="#reflect"></use>
    <g id="reflect">
        <templated-content class="blue" />
    </g>
</svg>

<svg>
    <use xlink:href="#reflect"></use>
    <g id="reflect">
        <templated-content class="red" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Will each reflection be red, or blue? Because the element can be reused, and each instance is potentially different, I can't rely on a constant `id` attribute.

I'd prefer to avoid assigning `id` pairs to each instance via script. I couldn't find anything useful in the [W3C xlink spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xlink11-20100506/#link-locators), but there's enough jargon there that I may have missed something.

Is there a supported way to include a **relative** `use`, or perhaps a similar result via another declarative feature?

EDIT: **I know it is invalid to include multiple elements with the same `id`.** That is why I want a way to create a reflection from a relative declarative reference. Can this be done?

Comment: Are you defining multiple elements with the same id in a single document? I think you might have issues with this.

Comment: Exactly, Kaiido. So how can I create a reflection without hard-coding an `id`?

Comment: well it depends on how you are creating those svgs

Comment: p.s. Just for the sake of clarity, I'm creating a component that isn't currently used in multiple instances at a time, however it could be. So, it's somewhat debatable whether hardcoding an `id` is a defect or not. Could be a case of YAGNI, if weighed against the need to attach non-standard DOM-manipulation code to the component. Just document the component limitations and call my job done. But, if there was a more technically correct way to do this, I wanted to do so before committing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having two items with the same id in the same document is invalid.

A `<use>` element must point to an id and each id must be unique, there's no such thing as a relative `<use>`

Each reflection should be blue.

You'll need to generate unique ids.

Comment: That isn't my question, Robert. My question is how to use a relative reference instead of an `id`, so that I don't have to generate unique `id`s.

Comment: That's not possible, hence my answer.

Comment: To clarify, the only way to use "`use`" for this purpose is with an `id`?

Comment: Kaiido correctly identified in his comment why I misread your solution. If that's what you mean, please clarify and I'll mark the answer accepted.